# "Upon receiving..." or "When receiving..."

Tags: word-choice

What is the proper word to use in the following sentences:

#### Example 1:

- "***When*** receiving a package, check the mailing address to ensure..."
- "***Upon*** receiving a package, check the mailing address to ensure..."

#### Example 2:

- "Then, ***when*** receiving a package, check the mailing address to ensure..."
- "Then, ***upon*** receiving a package, check the mailing address to ensure..."

What are the rules associated with when I should use "Upon" vs "When" in similar sentences to the example?

Comment: "Upon" in this context is now rather stiff and old fashioned. I see no other difference.

Comment: What @Colin said. More likely phrasing today would be ***On receipt of** a package...*

Comment: Hmm, I don't find "upon" old-fashioned or stiff.  This may be a regional thing.  (I'm in California.)  That being said, I find both words acceptable in this context.

Comment: You guys are brilliant. Seriously. Every time I've asked a question on this exchange I've gotten back so much information than I thought was possible. Love it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Practically-speaking '*when*' and '*upon*' are usually used to mean the same thing.

***When you get the parcel...*** means, effectively, the same as ***On receipt of the parcel...***

But they are not the same.

***When*** (in reference to a definite actual occurrence or fact) means *at the time that, on the occasion that*. (OED)

***Upon*** (often shortened to 'on') means *Immediately after; following on"* (OED)

So ...

The postman may ask you to sign for a parcel ***when*** it is delivered to you.  You, on the other hand, ***upon*** receipt of the parcel, may phone *in due course* to let your friend know that their parcel has arrived.

Comment: This is how I see it. Upon = after, When = at the time.

Answer (score 2):

As @Dan's answer suggests, *upon* should be interpreted as *after*, and *when* should be interpreted as *at the time*.

I'll give an example that might highlight the difference between the words.

> *When* receiving a gift from foreign dignitaries, you should take great care to admire the wrapping paper and delicately unwrap the present.
>
> *Upon* receiving a gift from foreign dignitaries, and pleasantries exchanged, the gift should be logged in the gift register.